# Search API- Force taxonomy terms to be indexed as one language

Tags: search

I have a non-multilingual taxonomy on a multilingual site.  All of the terms in the taxonomy are in English.

However, since this is a taxonomy of locations, some of the translations of the names of states/prefectures are in the database as part of the general interface translations.

I have a search index in Search API that indexes the taxonomy terms (field reference on a node) as type **taxonomy term**.  Somehow, Search API is sometimes picking up the translations when it is doing the index, so I get results like this:

- Tokyo (50)
- 東京 (25)

These are both Tokyo, just some of the entries are converted into Japanese.  The only thing I can think is that the author language is set to Japanese for the nodes that are coming up as Japanese.  However, when I display the data in a view, all of it shows up in English.

So, how can I force Search API to ignore translations when indexing taxonomy terms?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround: since I didn't need the translations in my case, I could go to the Translate UI screen and search for them and delete them one-by-one.  A real pain, but at least it cleared up the problem.